# Adding a degree symbol after content with CSS

Tags: css

I know that I can add a degree symbol in HTML with "&deg;", and I am looking at examples of CSS using :after selector and the content property, but I'm having trouble putting it all together.

I want a degree symbol to show up after the text that appears in an input box.

```
<div class="threshold">
    <input type="text" value="12" name="thresholdSelect" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.threshold input:after {
    content: "&deg;"
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas on how to fix it. I could store the degree symbol in the  value, but that would require a lot of extra javascript for things like validation and whatnot. Any way to do it with CSS?

Comment: Maybe `input.threshold:after {` will help?

Comment: I've always just put the actual character in there, rather than the entity.

Comment: As discussed below, a HTML solution is better as screen readers would have no concept of the unit of measurement used for your textbox. I would argue pseudo CSS elements shouldn't be used in this context, and should be reserved for display/styling only. If you add a label to the textbox which contains the unit of measurement then a CSS solution for the degree symbol would be acceptable.

Comment: Just don’t use a disabled input element. It mostly makes no sense (an element that accepts input but does not accept input).

Comment: removing disabled does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="threshold">
    <input type="text" value="12" name="thresholdSelect" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.threshold:before {
    content: "\00b0"
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tt2hU/ OR http://jsfiddle.net/Tt2hU/1/

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing it now. :after doesn't seem to work on input elements, so it's going to have to be wrapped in some way. Many Thanks!!

Comment: You can add `span` like this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Tt2hU/1/ or to add degree before `div`

Comment: Why is it '\00b0\ and not '\0176'?

Comment: @DevonDeason The degree sign in unicode is `U+00B0` thus `\00b0`

Answer (score 4):

should work like this

degrees° is done simply by

```
<p>degrees&#176;</p>
```

Comment: Understand the author asked for a CSS solution but semantically a HTML solution is better. Screen readers etc. would have no concept of the unit of measurement of the textbox.

Answer (score 4):

*You have to put in an escaped reference to the hexadecimal Unicode character value* (from [here](http://alanhogan.com/tips/css/special-characters-in-generated-content))

```
::after {
  content: "\00b0";
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V2Bqh/)

Answer (score 4):

This might help: [Can I use the :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)

It seems it may not be possible in CSS with an input tag.

Answer (score 2):

HTML entities doesn't work in CSS, you would use a character code entity, i.e. a backslash followed by a hexadecimal character code:

```
.threshold input:after {
  content: "\00b0";
}
```

However, this only works on regular elements, not input elements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/AcxEG/

Comment: The code in answer does not work because you have selected input `.threshold input:after`

Comment: @Enve: Do you mean in the demo? There the selector doesn't select the input, it only uses a class. I kept the original selector in the answer to keep it consistent with the question.